# Cordova 3.0 plugin tutorial

Tags: cordova, plugins

So the mess is even worse than two years ago.

Two years ago we tried a project with phonegap and came to the conclusion it was a documentation mess.

Now two years later we want to use it again in the hope some things had sorted out.

This isn't clearly the case.

What we want to do is write a cordova plugin "the right way"

Numerous tutorials and examples are doing "it" the 2.0 way, and tell us to change nonexisting files etc.

We already tried just copying the files and edit it the way we like it to be, but after a :
cordova plugin add ./plugins/nl.ourplugin it just empties the directory, and gone is the work.

So after numerous tries, we are just looking for a way to make a plugin the way it should be. To be reusable and not integrated in the source spagetti.

Does anybody know any resource that help you with "the way" to setup a cordova plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is

```
cordova plugin add X
```

where X is the ID of the plugin you want to add. You can also remove and list your current plugins. To find a plugin, you can search via the command line, or go to plugins.cordova.io.

This is discussed more in the CLI docs here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

To be clear, this about managing plugins. Documentation on using the plugin will be found on the individual plugin's web site. Remember, just because someone created a cool plugin does not mean they may have documented it well.